# How to set letter spacing for text in fyne-io/fyne?

Tags: go, fyne

I used a custom font, and the letter spacing looks too crowded.

I am trying to change the letter spacing, but I cannot find the configuration.
So I want to modify the source code, but I don't know where the letter spacing of text is set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It’s not set specifically anywhere, which is why you can’t find it.
This results in a mismatch between old text render code and newer shaping code.
This should be resolved before 2.4.0 as we move fully to new text rendering.

If you look into the source code you will find `TextDPI` internal constant set to `78` but the shaper is 72DPI.
Feel free to join our Slack or Discord servers/rooms linked at https://fyne.io/support/ to discuss more.